# Expressions: Data-generated After Effects Graphic using CSV file?

Tags: after-effects, premiere, after-effects-expressions, after-effects-scripting

Is there a way to read a CSV file or spreadsheet containing dates in timecode in one column and data in another column, then use the time/date to pair with footage to display the corresponding data?

Let's say I have a spreadsheet or csv with the number of sales a company has made in one column and in the other column a timestamp by the second or minute of when the sale was made. I then want to create a video showing in "real time" how many sales are being made during the action on screen.

I've seen a tutorial on reading arrays and importing that data into individual comps, but I'm wondering how I can sync data with video

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking. When you say "in real time" you don't mean you want it to change as the data changes? If so you're using the wrong ap. I you want to do a graph then yes, you can do it with expressions, but it might be easier to do it in Excel or illustrator and then animate in AE.

Comment: Not in real time in that way, as if the video is live, but rather to give the impression that the numbers updating correspond with the time within the video.

I am basically looking for a way to auto create text based on a spreadsheet, and have it be synced with footage.

Comment: So what is it you want to know? For how to  import data into expressions look here: http://blob.pureandapplied.com.au/using-data-from-an-external-file-to-drive-expressions/